# Determine the set of vectors $\vec{b} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ for which the matrix equation $A\vec{x} = \vec{b}$ in the variable $\vec{x}$ has a solution.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A be the following 3×3 matrix:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 
-3 & -9 & 8 \\
3 & 3 &-1\\
1&-1&2
\end{bmatrix}$$

Could anyone help me figure out how to solve this type of linear algebra question? I missed one of my math lectures and, although the question may be straightforward, I have no clues at this moment to crack it. Could anyone give me an example of solution to this type of Qs? Thanks a lot!^_^

Comment: @MorganRodgers Sir could you understand the title, I am really sorry as I am not good at using latex. I tried to use the codes to express the vector arrow but it seems that I failed..

Comment: Your coding seems to be flawless, but the question shouldn't appear only in the title. Put it also in the body of the question. For example, on my smartphone (i.e. now) the title doesn't compile and all I see is code (which is still understandable but a bit annoying) :)

Comment: @RedundantAunt Really sorry for the inconvenience.^_^ I will do that in the next time. Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to solve the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}-3x-9y+8z=a\\3x+3y-z=b\\x-y+2z=c\end{array}\right.$$By Gaussian elimination, you get\begin{align}\left\{\begin{array}{l}-3x-9y+8z=1\\3x+3y-z=b\\x-y+2z=c\end{array}\right.&\iff\left\{\begin{array}{l}x+3y-\frac83z=-\frac a3\\3x+3y-z=b\\x-y+2z=c\end{array}\right.\\&\iff\left\{\begin{array}{l}x+3y-\frac83z=-\frac a3\\-6y+7z=a+b\\-4y+\frac{14}3z=\frac a3+c\end{array}\right.\\&\iff\left\{\begin{array}{l}x+3y-\frac83z=-\frac a3\\y-\frac76z=-\frac a6-\frac b6\\-4y+\frac{14}3z=\frac a3+c\end{array}\right.\\&\iff\left\{\begin{array}{l}x+3y-\frac83z=-\frac a3\\y-\frac76z=-\frac a6-\frac b6\\-4y+\frac{14}3z=\frac a3+c\end{array}\right.\\&\iff\left\{\begin{array}{l}x+3y-\frac83z=-\frac a3\\y-\frac76z=-\frac a6-\frac b6\\0=-\frac13a-\frac23b+c.\end{array}\right.\end{align}Now, the last line tells you when the system has a solution. It's when $-a-2b+3c=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I now totally got this. I think I need to master the knowledge of Gaussian elimination. ^_^

Comment: @DannyC I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Thank you very much professor^_^!